# Ionic 3 make promise funtion in constructor

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

How can we make a promise function in constructor that run line by line and wait for it's result then go to next line. Currently my promise function is not running and it runs in last.

```
constructor(){
    console.log("Start");
    this.getData();
    console.log("End");
}

getData() {
   return new Promise(data => {
     this.db.database.ref().child('/category').orderByChild('parent_id').
       equalTo(this.idn).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
         console.log("Mid")
       })
   });
}
```

output of above is

```
Start
End
Mid
```

Expected output is

```
Start
Mid
End
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify, your promise function does not run last. It starts after "Start" and before "End", as expected. It just happens to *finish last*. This is because it is an "async" call by design. (Async == non-blocking means the program does not wait for it to finish. It just moves on to the next statement, console.log("End"), in your example.)

BTW, calling methods like "getData()" in Ctor is not a good practice. You may want to do it in an Angular lifecycle method like `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: is there any way that program wait for it to finish that first?

Comment: That's what the ".then()" method is for as other answers suggest. Anything that should happen _after_ the data has been fetched, in your example, should be done withing the .then() method.

Comment: actually my main problem is that in `then()` method I am not able to assign value like `this.key=2;` it give me error that's why I post this so that program wait.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? It's possible that you might not have access to "this" inside these nested handlers. You might have to save "this" to a variable so that it can be called within these methods. Or, there are alternative ways. For example, define a member method, in which you do "this.key=2", and call this method within "then()", etc.  Cannot recall what I usually do, but try these approaches and see if they work.

Answer (score 2):

Since getData function return a promise, resolve it and put the console inside it

```
constructor(){
    console.log("Start");
    this.getData().then(function (snapshot) {             
        console.log("End");
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling getData() method  in Constructor is not a good practice & harms the app performance. I would recommend using [ionViewDidLoad](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) instead for ionic, this is what you need in almost all cases.

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    console.log("Start");
    this.getData();
}

getData() {
   return new Promise(data => {
     this.db.database.ref().child('/category').orderByChild('parent_id').
       equalTo(this.idn).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
         console.log("Mid"),
         //put the code you want to execute after Mid here
         console.log("End");

       })
   });
}
```